# What to test in log in page?

Tags: testing, authentication

What is to test in log in page other than :

1. data type (letter,number,special case, length rule)
2. all the buttons functions
3. connections
4. usability-fonts,spelling ect

Answer (score 0):

One useful function to test for is the re-population of the username when the login fails, as it's usually a mistyped password.